# Cannot connect to database by remote server

Tags: php, mysql

i have this problem:

I've created a Cms on my server hosted in Aruba (i call this My-server), i need to connect to a remote server (i call this external-server) to update its Database (Mysql) and ftp uploads via php. 
I opened ports and connection in the external-server but it seems that Aruba blocks connection to external servers, even if tunnelling by port 80.

When i use my cms from virtual server (APache) on my laptop all works but when i moved to the server i got problems.

Any advice to solve the problem?

I cannot move my cms to external-server for politicy reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your MySQL config add this
skip-external-locking

and in the config also remove this line below as if this is in place then no outsider can login.

## bind-address           = 127.0.0.1

restart the MYSQL after this.

Comment: also check your iptables. iptables -L. see if there is a block on 3306 port, if there is then remove that.

Answer (score 0):

You can asked Aruba to provide you access to port 80, 3306 etc. Just ask them I think they will remove it through their firewalls or iptables.